# Mysql сравнение данных 2-х таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Имеется следующая задача.

В базе находятся 2 таблицы: actual_test и tmp_test. Обе таблицы имеют абсолютно одинаковую структуру. В таблицу tmp_test каждые N часов пишутся некоторые данные.

Как можно реализовать следующее. Если записи из таблицы tmp_test отличаются от записей в таблице actual_test, обновить соответствующие записи в actual_test.

Пример:

Содержимое actual_test (Внешний ключ, столбец 1, столбец 2)

```
1,AAA,123
2,BBB,345
3,CCC,678
```

Содержимое tmp_test (Внешний ключ, столбец 1, столбец 2)

```
1,AAA,123
2,BAB,345
3,CCC,778
```

Обновляем записи в actual_test c 2,BBB,345 на 2,BAB,345 и 3,CCC,678 на 3,CCC,778

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Репликацию одной таблицы можно реализовать с помощью движка для таблиц FEDERATED и указать host=127.0.0.1.

Можно еще с триггерами поиграться - каждое изменение tmp_test вызывает триггер, который обновляет теми-же данными actual_test

Answer (score 2):

Можно примерно так:

```
UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.p1 = t2.p1, t1.p2 = t2.p2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND (t1.p1 <> t2.p1 OR t1.p2 <> t2.p2)
```

Где t1 - первая таблица, t2 - вторая.
id - идентификатор каждой строки, на что опираемся для сравнения.
p1..p2 - параметры, которые необходимо сравнить и заменить.

Comment: Спасибо. То же думал над таким решением. А нет ли аналога репликации, но только для таблиц?

Comment: @Nicholas Essen: ENGINE=federate

Comment: @boris_U Спасибо за наводку. Но, на сколько я понял из документации, движок federated предоставляет возможность получить данные из таблицы на удаленной базе. Но нет возможности отследить изменения в этой таблице. Моя задача иная. Обе таблицы находятся в одной базе, на одном и том же сервере. Так же, нужно отслеживать изменения в одной из этих таблиц. На сколько я понял, движок federated не позволяет отслеживать изменения.

Comment: @boris_U Спасибо. Не могли бы ли Вы преобразовать комментарий в ответ? Я Вам плюсик поставлю.